# Make sure search engines and bots don't find my cms page

Tags: php, .htaccess, search, bots

He I was just wondering how to not be found by Google or any search engine or bot. And then I mean a specific page of a website like the cms page. Also its handy for online applications witch are only meant to be used by a small group of people and are not meant for the searchers on Google.

My colleges gave me this (I am confined that this is not the best and dynamic solution):

```
...
<Files .htaccess> 
  deny from all 
</Files>

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} HTTrack [NC,OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR] 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus 
...
```

I tried to Google this but I only find information about getting search engine to find the page and I want the opposite.

O yes I use Apache In combo wit PHP, I don't know if I can do something form within my PHP script to block a bot request.

Comment: only 100% solution dont put on the internet\put behind login. black listing user agent is pointless. bad bots use fake ones, good bots floow the robots.txt or meta robots tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I block search crawlers for every site on an Apache web server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227101/can-i-block-search-crawlers-for-every-site-on-an-apache-web-server)

Comment: @Dagon Ok but lets pretend this is just for the cms. And who downvoted me is this such a bad question to ask?

Comment: pretend anything you like, cms or not, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Use a robots.txt file. See http://www.robotstxt.org/

Your config above is silly. It will only work for the bots you know about, not for any you don't know about, or any that don't exist yet.

Comment: Bad bots will pretend to be a real web browser, and you absolutely cannot stop them seeing your site - there is no way to tell they are not a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a little more clear with what you are trying to block. You mentioned "like a cms page". Does this mean you want the login screen to be hidden as well? The internal CMS pages will always remain hidden from bots because bots don't (shouldn't) know your username/passwords.

If you personally go to the hypothetical URL `www.mycms.com/add_article.php` without logging in then are you allowed in to create an article? If your answer is YES then you have far more problems to deal with before you can even begin to worry about bots.

The .htaccess code that your colleagues gave you merely provides a rudimentary solution if you find that your website bandwidth is being consumed by bots. There are websites completely dedicated to exposing these "bad bots". Start by checking out this article http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2067357/Bye-bye-Crawler-Blocking-the-Parasites

If you do everything right then the login page will be the ONLY page that a bot can visit. If you are looking to prevent your login page from being visited by bots then make sure that your URL is never posted on public websites like forums because both good and bad bots will scour the forums and follow any URL they can find.

Also, will this website be used strictly by people you work with on the company intranet? If so then look into setting up an intranet-only website/server. Ask the networking gurus at your company and you won't believe how easy it is.

One last thing you can research: .htpasswd

Good luck!